UiAutomator focus not updating after movement
I'm using UiAutomator to test an Android TV app.
I will often need to scroll to a specific resource so I will do a loop such as:
while(device.findObject(By.focused(true)).resourceName != 'MyResourceName') {
   device.pressDPadRight()
   device.waitForIdle()
}

This often fails/runs forever due to the UiObject being returned by the findObject() call not updating.
Is this a known deficiency with UiAutomator, a potential problem in the code of the Android TV application, or am I navigating/checking focus incorrectly?
